# How to add IP addresses to squid's whitelist

Tags: acl, squid

I cannot find how to add IP addresses to squid's whitelist.

For example, I'd like to add address `130.125.110.20`, or all addresses of network 130.125.110.*, or maybe only a defined port only `130.125.110.20:443`.

So I'm expecting someting like `acl whitelist IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the next line:

Acl your_network_name src xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Http_access allow your_network_name

You have to restart your squid server after adding a new acl entry, also you have to be carefull about which acls you are blocking and which you allow